# Is there a setting to automatically Refresh Dashboard Data on a user login, or when returning to CiviCRM Home?

Tags: dashboard, user, user-dashboard, user-interface, user-experience

We're on Civi 4.6.17 and Drupal 7.

I'm looking for a way for users to be able to select an option to be able to automatically Refresh Dashboard Data on login, or when returning to their  CiviCRM Home page, without having to click on Refresh Dashboard Data.

Better, is there a way to have this be the default action with an admin setting.

Is/are there such a setting(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such setting exists, although, you can set the timeout for the Dashboard cache navigating to **Administer - System settings - Misc** and set the the **Dashboard cache timeout** to the value desired in minutes, setting it to 1 minute for example it will refresh the Dashboard data every minute.

I guess the other option would be to create an extension and use the [resetDashletCache](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php#L558) method on login

Comment: Andrei, thanks, will check out those two methods.